# Stuck at Go syntax error that I can't see

Tags: go

I am getting a syntax error and I can't figure out why. I have tried several variations but no success.

```
type dataType int64

const (
    PM_SENT dataType = iota + 1
    PM_VIEWED
)

func messageHandler(m []byte) error {
    var data map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(m, &data); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    var dt dataType
    flt, ok := data["type"].(float64); ok {
        dt = dataType(flt)
    }

    return nil
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
.\messageHandler.go:23: syntax error: unexpected =, expecting comma or }
```

Even if I change to this I still get the same error:

```
var dt int64
flt, ok := data["type"].(float64)
if ok {
    dt = int64(flt)
}
```

Comment: The first example is missing an `if`. The second example won't have the exact same error, so make sure your code is saved, and show the error you're getting.

Comment: You are absolutely right. The second one gave ".\messageHandler.go:20: dt declared and not used"

Comment: Then you haven't used `dt`. show a complete example if you're not sure what that means.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code doesn't throw any error:

```
if flt, ok := data["type"].(float64); ok {
    dt = int64(flt)
}
```